# Angular no reconoce la hoja de estilos

Tags: html, css, angular

Aunque a priori es una pregunta sencilla, no sé que mas soluciones darle.

Quiero cambiar de manera dinámica mi hoja de estilos en angular, sin embargo cuando la importo en el index.html esta no me la reconoce. Ambas hojas de estilo las tengo importadas en el Angular.json. El path de ambas esta bien señalado.

No sé, si es que habrá alguna propiedad de angular que omita el stylesheet.
Os dejo el código:

Angular.Json

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles/styles.scss",
              {
                "input": "src/styles/hoja2.scss",
                "bundleName": "demo-style",
                "inject": false
             
              }
```

HTML:

```
 <link id="main-theme" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/hoja2.scss">
```

A parte de eso siempre sale cargada la hoja styles.scss. No sé si es que se guarda en otra parte del DOM.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2):

Se ha solucionado utilizando Renderer2.

Al tener la Clase renderer2, primero he tenido que crear una estancia con RendererFactory2:

Os dejo el código.

```
public setTheme(theme: string) {
        if (theme === '' || theme === 'styles' || !theme) {
            console.log('No hay ninguna hoja de estilos en esta App.');
        } else {
            const link = this.render.selectRootElement('.main-theme')
            //const link = this.element.nativeElement;
            this.render.setAttribute(link, 'src', 'styles/' + theme + '.scss');
            this.render.appendChild(document.head, link);
        }
    }
```